# Implement zimJS inside Angular4(typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, createjs

I googled and look'd everywhere to find the answer. No modules for zimjs, only for createjs but i need the whole thing.

I couldn't find anything that could help me.

I would like to use [THIS](http://zimjs.com) framework inside angular and typescript.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I guess you just add the JS file to your page, then, in the normal way

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I doesn't recognize it in typescript. @ADyson
Here is my index.hml https://pastebin.com/s6BMU1Jc

Comment: why don't you embed it in a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZIM has TypeScript typings available here: https://zimjs.com/typescript/ I know this is only partially addresses your question - but it will hopefully help.  It is no small feat with 3600 lines of definitions...

A ES6 ZIM module was started but got stalled.  There is a GitHub issue here: https://github.com/danzen/zimjs/issues/8 with respect to NPM if you care to follow that - or perhaps contribute.